# virtual inheritance member lookup

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have following code for inherited virtual classes and somehow `inh::P1` is compiled as `char`. Can anyone please explain why the compiler chooses `char` over `int` for `inh::P1` in this example? Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

class myClass {public: typedef int P1;};
class myClassdef : virtual public myClass {};
class myClass2 : virtual public myClass { public: typedef char P1;};
class inh :  public myClassdef, public myClass2 {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(inh::P1) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sizeof(inh::P1);
```

The lookup happens from the most immediate level and upwards hence `inh::P1` refers to `P1` which is inherited through `myClass2`, which is indeed of the *type*, `char`. If you need  to refer the member in topmost base class use:

```
  sizeof(myClass::P1);
```

Note that:

```
inh::P1          --->  Refers to immediate base member, i.e: myClass2::P1
myClass2::P1     --->  Refers to member in current class scope, i.e: myClass2::P1
myClassdef::P1   --->  Refers to immediate base member, i.e: myClass::P1
myClass::P1      --->  Refers to member in current class scope, i.e: myClass::P1
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically in multiple inheritance the lookup is done on the nearest level, due to which when you call inh::P1, P1 of myClass2 is called.
So, if you want to refer myClass then call it explicitly as below:

```
sizeof(myClass::P1);
```